# Azure redirect non-www to www

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have question about Azure redirection.

I have searched other topics but not quite my problem(s).

I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 project and Azure configured for that. Also i have domain for pointing to Azure.
I have added www.example.com format domain to azure and that works fine also with https.

Problem rises with example.com format

I wanted to redirect example.com format to www.example.com URL

I manage to get this work with this, but for little while.
I use this web.config for redirection

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Something strange is Google Chrome & Opera redirect(s) to www domain but not Edge and Firefox.
Then when i clear cache(s) then it wont redirect.

Seems like Azure like rewrites some over or something.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Have you checked your F12 tools in those browsers, are you receiving the 302 redirect?

Comment: in Edge, Press F12 to view the browser console then press Network to view traffic. Compare it to the same thing in chrome. Anything different?

Comment: Im not recieving any 302 code. Problem is also why its not working after clearing cache?!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the web.config file changes, ensure the Azure Website instance contains the correct domain bindings within the `Hostname bindings` area.

```
<rule name="Redirect to www">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```